# Cómo combinar dos listas por un indice en Java de Android

Tags: java, android, lista

Tengo dos listas `rutasES` y `rutasEN` que almacenan información de rutas dependiendo de su idioma, obtenidas previamente de una base de datos `realm.io`.

Las dos listas tiene los mismos campos `List<Route>`:

`id`, `ref`,`title`,`location`,`description`

El `ref` es el identificador común de la ruta, el `id`es la posición dentro de la BD, solo sirve para saber cual se refiere.

**rutasES**

```
1,SL01, ruta por Madrid, Madrid, la ruta empieza....
2,SL02, ruta por Barcelona, Barcelona, la ruta empieza...
```

**rutasEN**

```
3,SL02, Barcelona route, Barcelona, the route start....
```

La idea es realizar más o menos como hace Android con los `strings.xml`, que si no está definido en un idioma, coge de la base.

Quiero mostrar las rutas en ingles `rutasEn` pero ajuntando la ruta que no esté traducida.

digamos en pseudo-código lo haría así:

```
llenar `listaFinal` con `rutasES`
comprobar el campo `ref` de rutasEN si está en la `listaFinal`
    Si: modificar los datos con los de `rutasEn`
    No: continuar
```

El resultado final debería ser:

```
1,SL01, ruta por Madrid, Madrid, la ruta empieza....
3,SL02, Barcelona route, Barcelona, the route start....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mi solución, seguramente se puede arreglar hacerlo más óptimo, pero mis conocimientos en Java son de novato.

```
import java.lang.Math; // headers MUST be above the first class
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

// one class needs to have a main() method
public class HelloWorld
{
  // arguments are passed using the text field below this editor
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<TestObj> mListES = new ArrayList<TestObj>();
    List<TestObj> mListEN = new ArrayList<TestObj>();
    List<TestObj> mListFinal = new ArrayList<TestObj>();

    //Enter Data de testeo    
    mListES.add(new TestObj(1,"sl01","ruta1 espaool","texto en espanol"));
    mListES.add(new TestObj(2,"sl02","ruta1 espaool","texto en espanol"));
    mListES.add(new TestObj(3,"sl03","ruta3 espaool","texto en espanol"));
    mListES.add(new TestObj(4,"sl04","ruta4 espaool","texto en espanol"));

    //mListEN.add(new TestObj(5,"sl01","route1 english","text in english"));
    //mListEN.add(new TestObj(6,"sl02","route2 english","text in english"));
    mListEN.add(new TestObj(7,"sl03","route3 english","text in english"));
    //mListEN.add(new TestObj(8,"sl04","route4 english","text in english"));

    //Crear lista final con la lista en English y lo que falte en Espanol

    mListFinal = mListES;

    for (int i = 0; i < mListFinal.size(); i++) {

      String srch = mListFinal.get(i).getRef();

      int index = searchInList(mListEN,srch); 
      if ( index != -1 ) {
        //System.out.println(mListEN.get(index));
        mListFinal.set(i,mListEN.get(index));
      } else {
          //System.out.println(mListFinal.get(i));
      }
    }


      System.out.println("");
      System.out.println("Final list");

    for (int i = 0; i < mListFinal.size(); i++) {
      System.out.println(mListFinal.get(i));
    }



  }

  public static int searchInList(List<TestObj> mArray,String search) {

    int out = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < mArray.size(); i++) {
      if (mArray.get(i).getRef().equals(search)) {
        out = i;
        //System.out.println("found it" + mArray.get(i));

      }
    }

    return out;

  }


}




class TestObj {

        private int id;
        private String ref;
        private String title;
        private String summary;

        public TestObj() {

        }


        public TestObj(int id, String str1, String str2, String str3){
            this.id = id;
            this.ref = str1;
            this.title = str2;
            this.summary= str3;
        }

        public String getRef() {
            return this.ref;
        }

        public void setTitle(String str) {
            this.title = str;
        }

        public void setSummary(String str) {
            this.summary = str;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return this.title;
        }

        public String getSummary() {
            return this.summary;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return id + " " +this.getRef() + " " + this.getTitle();
        }

}
```

La salida es:

```
Final list
1 sl01 ruta1 espaool
2 sl02 ruta1 espaool
7 sl03 route3 english
4 sl04 ruta4 espaool
```

Answer (score 1):

Tal cual como Android lo hace, tu tendrias que implementar tu solucion de union de las dos listas.

Mi aproximacion seria que cuando se te solicite un elemento de la lista que no es la base, ir y buscarlo, y si no se encuentra un elemento que coincida con ese indice, entonces obtener el elemento de la lista base.

Para encontrar los elementos en las listas, podrias recorrer la lista hasta encontrar los elementos, o podrias usar un filtro

```
Route getRoute(int searchedId){
    Route R = null;
    for (Route r : rutasES)
        if (r.id == searchedId){ //asumiendo id es entero
            R = r; break;
        }
    //verificamos si se encontro la ruta en la lista ES
    if (R != null){
        for (Route r : rutasEN)
            if (r.id == searchedId){ //asumiendo id es entero
                R = r; break;
            }
    }
    return R;
}
```

Si el elemento se encontró en la lista ES, entonces devuelve el elemento buscado, si no, entonces lo busca en la lista EN, y lo devuelve. Si no lo encontro en ninguna list,a entonces devuelve nulo.

para las busquedas tambien puedes usar filtros

```
Route objES = rutasES.stream().filter(c-> c.id == searchedId).findFirst().get();
```

En general reducen el tamaño del codigo, pero siempre que las he usado los indices si existen en la lista, y no se como reaccionarian con indices faltantes.